# installing rails 4.0.5 for Michael Hartl tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, railstutorial.org

Fairly new to all this, so please do excuse the novice in me. So I just purchased the full package from Michael Hartl's rails tutorial website. I am running into some issues setting up the dev environment.

I used Rails Installer to get things going, and it installed the works. The only issue here is that it installed a version of Rails newer than 4.1, to follow Hartl's tutorial I need 4.0.5. When I type in gem rails -v in the CMD, it says Rails 4.1.1.

How would I go about installing an older version, such as 4.0.5, and having only that one run, instead of 4.1.1?

I do appreciate all the help as I am very eager to get started with RoR and to follow Hartl's tutorial. He does say in the tutorial that it will not work if I am not able to install the correct versions of Rails, so I am really stuck here.

Thank-you.

edit: I am on Windows 7, and am using Sublime Text Editor 3 as well.

Comment: `gem install rails -v 4.0.5`

Comment: I did this, and then when I checked the current version, it still says 4.1.1. Also, not sure if those library errors had anything to do with it?

http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a96/gstuto/railsinstallcmd-1.jpg

Comment: the easiest thing to do would be just to remove 4.1.1. (`gem uninstall rails -v 4.1.1`). Alternatively, you can specify which version of rails to use when running commands, eg. `rails _4.0.5_ -v`

Comment: Ok, I also went to another post and found a different way to uninstall 4.1.1 which was by doing uninstall railties.... Now, the current version does read 4.0.5 thanks to your suggestion, however, do those errors that show when I try doing "install v 4.0.5 etc" mean anything? or will I be ok?

http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a96/gstuto/railsinstallcmd2.jpg

Comment: they're okay, you can safely ignore them. They only occur when installing the documentation for the gem (a step a lot of people skip anyway).

Comment: ok great, thank-you! going to get to the next part of his tutorial now!

Answer (score 1):

First install the version that you want, as others said in the comments:

```
gem install rails -v 4.0.5
```

Then just create the new project as follows:

```
rails _version_ new appName
```

Using your desired version:

```
rails _4.0.5_ new appName
```

This way the project will be created with the version specified.

**Don't worry if you have more than one version of Rails installed**